# Deploying Kudu on a server

Tags: git, iis, deployment

I have setup a copy of [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/) on my local dev machine, and it works fine providing I run it from Visual Studio as Administrator

I would now like to deploy it to our public UAT server so we can use it for deploying testing sites.
The UAT server is Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have followed the ["Deploying to a server"](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-to-a-server) instructions, however when I load the site I get the error:

```
You are running kudu against a local kudu service and are not an Administrator. Re-run this process as Administrator in order to continue.
```

While I understand Kudu needs to run as admin to create sites etc, I don't feel comfortable giving a public site admin privileges (even though it will have some form of authentication once I get it running).

The "Deploying to a server" instructions makes no mention of Administrator privileges, and I'm unable to find much documentation on the topic.

Anyway one had any luck with this?

Comment: Submitted an issue on [Kudus](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/) traker [#1486](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1486) for those who are interested

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue. Open visual studio as admin: right click on the visual studio icon and  you should see an option, something like 'open as admin'